# ServiceLoader.next causing a NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, serviceloader

I'm asking because I'm totally *not* sure I've done the right thing. I'm using Eclipse for a web project. Let's call it WebProject (duh) in the package `com.web.project`.

I want WebProject to load JAR plugins at runtime, so I thought I could take advantage of `java.util.ServiceLoader`. So I created an interface `com.web.project.WebProjectPlugin` in the WebProject project with all the methods the plugins must implement.

Then I created the project PluginProject, adding WebProbject/build/classes in its Build path as a class folder:

```
package com.web.project.plugin;

import com.web.project.WebProjectPlugin;

public class TestPlugin implements WebProjectPlugin {
    // Implementation of the interface methods...
}
```

Then I created a META-INF/services folder in the plugin project, put the text file `com.web.project.WebProjectPlugin` inside, containing the sole line "com.web.project.plugin.TestPlugin".

I exported the JAR file checking out the added build/classes folder and put it somewhere in the hard drive. When WebProject starts up, it does the following:

```
File[] jlist = pluginsDir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.getPath().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jar");
    }
});
URL[] urls = new URL[jlist.length];
for (int i = 0; i < jlist.length; i++)
    urls[i] = jlist[i].toURI().toURL();
URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

ServiceLoader<WebProjectPlugin> srvl =
    ServiceLoader.load(WebProjectPlugin.class, ucl);
Iterator<WebProjectPlugin> iter = srvl.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    WebProjectPlugin plugin = iter.next();
    plugins.add(plugin);
}
```

`pluginsDir` is a `File` object pointing to the directory the JAR file is in. At first it seems that `srvl` does its job, since `iter` isn't empty, but then it throws the dreaded `NoClassDefFoundError` when it reaches `iter.next()`.

I've already managed to create a plugin manager project to test `ServiceLoader`, and it runs just fine, but it's a plain console Java application, not a web project. So, what am I doing wrong here?

I'm a little puzzled: how can it *not* find the class definition for `com.web.project.WebProjectPlugin`, since it's in the same project that is running? Has that something to do with the `URLClassLoader` object I'm using?

This is the [stack trace](http://pastebin.com/fMhRESK2).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try assigning the parent classloader to your `URLClassLoader`

```
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
```

A WebProject expects a certain hierarchy of class loaders, so it might be that your classes are not visible to each other if the parent/child hieararchy is not set properly.

Comment: I think you meant `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`, but you know what? It runs just fine! Thanks!