# ClassNotFoundException when using ServiceLoader in Glassfish4 Java EE app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, serviceloader

In a Java EE application, I'm trying to load serviced using Java's [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html). The .jar file I'm trying to load works in a test Java SE application, so I assume it's correct. However, the below code fails at `itr.next`:

```
ServiceLoader<WorkflowStepSPI> loader = ServiceLoader.load(WorkflowStepSPI.class, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        loader.reload();
        List<String> names = new LinkedList<>();
        Iterator<WorkflowStepSPI> itr = loader.iterator();
        while ( itr.hasNext() ) {
            WorkflowStepSPI wss = itr.next();
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Found WorkflowStepProvider: {0}", wss.getClass().getCanonicalName());
            names.add(wss.toString());
        }
```

The exception thrown in ClassNotFoundException, complaining about not being able to find `WorkflowStepSPI`, which is clearly there (otherwise the code would not compile). In another test, I validated that `Class.forName` returns this class.

I have tried to create my own URLClassLoader instance as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295080/serviceloader-next-causing-a-noclassdeffounderror), and loading the class directly as suggested [here](https://javaevangelist.blogspot.com/2013/11/serviceloader-dynamic-reloading-on-jee7.html), but for no avail.

Any ideas?

*** Update ***

As requested, here's the stack trace:

```
Warning:   Class not found: edu/harvard/iq/dataverse/workflow/WorkflowStepSPI
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/harvard/iq/dataverse/workflow/WorkflowStepSPI
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1730)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:370)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at edu.harvard.iq.dataverse.api.WorkflowsAdmin.testSpi(WorkflowsAdmin.java:215)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:205)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at edu.harvard.iq.dataverse.api.ApiBlockingFilter$3.doBlock(ApiBlockingFilter.java:65)
at edu.harvard.iq.dataverse.api.ApiBlockingFilter.doFilter(ApiBlockingFilter.java:157)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at edu.harvard.iq.dataverse.api.ApiRouter.doFilter(ApiRouter.java:30)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:873)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
at edu.harvard.iq.dataverse.api.ApiRouter.doFilter(ApiRouter.java:34)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.harvard.iq.dataverse.workflow.WorkflowStepSPI
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 94 more
```

Comment: Where is the stacktrace your are getting? What class is missing according to the stack trace? What does your deployment structure look like? Are you deploying a war file with jar file as dependency, or directly jar file? Can you post a simplified version of your app on github? ServiceLoaders work just fine on EE containers, so I assume your issue is caused by a more fundamental problem in your deployment.

Comment: The project is a standard .war file, based on maven. This happens on my laptop with a local Glassfish 4.1, Mac OS. The .jar with the SPI implementation is in the domain/lib folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, a `NoClassDefError` (as opposed to a `ClassNotFoundException`) occurs when a statically compiled class is not available at runtime (`ClassNotFoundException` happens when you try to get a class by reflection that simply isn't there, for example using `Class.forName()`).

What happened is that when you compiled your code, the class was present in the classpath. However, for various reasons (that are impossible to determine without seeing your configuration) the class is not available on the server. The possible reasons for that are:

- it is part of another project that you cross-compiled your project against (that generated .class files) and that other project is not included in the WAR (for example because it had a different output directory whose contents were not copied to `WEB-INF/classes`)
- it was included in a library that for some reasons was not shipped together with the WAR
- your WAR is malformed and does not contain the proper structure (class files should go in `WEB-INF/classes`, libraries should go in `WEB-INF/lib`)
- you are running the server on a different Java distribution than the one which you compiled the code (clearly not the case here due to the package of the class, but just wanted to point it out for completeness)

Generally, it is bad practice to rely on application-specific WARs to be bundled together with the server (in some server specific folders). Moreover, it generates subtle errors because of some classloader separation issues on application servers. Instead, your WAR should contain the required jars packaged within.

Answer (score 0):

Putting @piotr-wilkin's excellent answer to practice, here's the status I had and how I solved this.

**Starting point**

To save time (the irony!) I used the .war file of the web application as a dependency for the SPI implementation project. This allowed me to use the classes from the main project at the SPI implementation. But apparently it confused Glassfish's class loader (as states in the question, Java SE's class loader was fine with this).

**Fix**

1. I created a new .jar file with the interface the SPI should implement. That jar file was added as a dependency to both the web application and the SPI implementation project.
2. Packed the .jar of the SPI as usual (`META-INF/services/.....`).
3. Added both the .jar of the SPI implementation AND the .jar of the interface to the domain's `lib` folder.
4. Restarted Glassfish

Now, I do realize that I have two copies of the interface, which I'm not too happy about. But as it's just an interface and contains no state at any static fields, I think that's more of an aesthetic issue.